# Convert array of data into an object with properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How do I convert an array into an object with properties:
With the following data:
`["Test Scenario ID", "Login-1"]`

I would like to return an object with properties:

```js
{1: "Test Scenario ID", 2: "Login-1"} // desired result
```

With the following, It maps the data into separate objects, but I would like it to be properties of a single object instead of an array of objects:

```js
row.values.map( (e,i) => { return {i: e} })

[{1: "Test Scenario ID"}, {2: "Login-1"}] // the current result
```

Comment: How does changing your data to this format help you? It seems entirely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `Object.fromEntries` to turn an array of entries into the object.

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  row.values.map((e, i) => [i, e])
);
```

Another option is to take your array of multiple objects and put it through `Object.assign` to combine them.

```
const result = Object.assign(
  ...row.values.map( (e,i) => ({i: e}))
);
```

Comment: How would I use fromEntries if there is an undefined/null entry? e.g.:  null, 4, "View nearby bucket lists"

Comment: Would you want to remove such values from the resulting object?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']);    // {0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"}
```

> The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from
> one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the modified
> target object.

you can read more about it [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)